# Request fields in Python Facebook SDK

Tags: python, facebook

This is the way I am currently fetching the `/me` object:

`self.facebook_user = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token).get_object('me')`

But if I want, for example, to request only the `name` and `id` fields from `/me`, how do I build the request?

Comment: maybe try `self.facebook_user = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token).get_object('me?fields=name,id')`

Comment: It throws me this error: `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass in extra query parameters using **args:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object('me')
args = {'fields' : 'id,name,email', }
profile = graph.get_object('me', **args)
```