# Reading page's messages with Python Facebook SDK

Tags: python, facebook, sdk

Basically i need to get all messages of a page using facebook SDK in python.
Following some tutorial i arrived to this point:

```
import facebook

def main():
  cfg = {
    "page_id"      : "MY PAGE ID", 
    "access_token" : "LONG LIVE ACCESS TOKEN"  
    }

  api = get_api(cfg)
  msg = "Hre"
  status = api.put_wall_post(msg) #used to post to wall message Hre
  x = api.get_object('/'+str(MY PAGE ID)+"/conversations/") #Give actual  conversations


def get_api(cfg):
  graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cfg['access_token'])
  resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
  page_access_token = None
  for page in resp['data']:
    if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
      page_access_token = page['access_token']
  graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
  return graph

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The first problem is that  `api.get_object('/'+str(MY PAGE ID)+"/conversations/")`returns a dictionary containing many informations, but what i would like to see is the messages they sent to me, while for now it print the user id that sent to me a message.

The output look like the following:

```
{u'paging': {u'next': u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/571499452991432/conversations?access_token=Token&limit=25&until=1441825848&__paging_token=enc_AdCqaKAP3e1NU9MGSsvSdzDPIIDtB2ZCe2hCYfk7ft5ZAjRhsuVEL7eFYOOCdQ8okvuhZA5iQWaYZBBbrZCRNW8uzWmgnKGl69KKt4catxZAvQYCus7gZDZD', u'previous': u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/571499452991432/conversations?access_token=token&limit=25&since=1441825848&__paging_token=enc_AdCqaKAP3e1NU9MGSsvSdzDPIIDtB2ZCe2hCYfk7ft5ZAjRhsuVEL7eFYOOCdQ8okvuhZA5iQWaYZBBbrZCRNW8uzWmgnKGl69KKt4catxZAvQYCus7gZDZD&__previous=1'}, u'data': [{u'link': u'/communityticino/manager/messages/?mercurythreadid=user%3A1055476438&threadid=mid.1441825847634%3Af2e0247f54f5c4d222&folder=inbox', u'id': u't_mid.1441825847634:f2e0247f54f5c4d222', u'updated_time': u'2015-09-09T19:10:48+0000'}]}
```

which is basically `paging` and `data`.
Given this is there a way to read the conversation?

Comment: Since you just exposed your long-lived page access token here, you should go change your Facebook password __now__ to invalidate it.

Comment: You need to ask for the fields that you want

Comment: @CBROE thanks for the answer ! Really usless

Comment: WizKid where can I find the fields I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the messages content you need first to request the single messages in the conversation, accessible with the 'id' field in the dictionary you copied, result of 
    x = api.get_object('/'+str(MY PAGE ID)+"/conversations/") #Give actual  conversations

you can request the messages in the conversation by calling

```
msg = api.get_object('/'+<message id>)
```

Here it gets tricky, because following the graph api documentation you should receive back a dictionary with ALL the possible fields, including the 'message' (content) field. The function however returns only the fields 'created_time' and 'id'.
Thanks to this other question [Request fields in Python Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669977/request-fields-in-python-facebook-sdk) I found that you can request for those fields by adding a dict with such fields specified in the arguments of the graph.get_object() function. As far as I know this is undocumented in the facebook sdk reference for python.

The correct code is

```
args = {'fields' : 'message'}
msg = api.get_object('/'+<message id>, **args)
```

Similar question: [Read facebook messages using python sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157754/read-facebook-messages-using-python-sdk#new-answer)